# "Be about to'' vs. "Be going to"

Tags: grammar, adverbs, infinitives, participles

If you say *"something is about to happen"* or *"something is going to happen"*, you mean that *"it will happen very soon"* :

> The man is about to die.
>
> The man is going to die.

What is the difference between the two sentences, both in structure and in meaning?

Answer (score 1):

"About to" implies immediacy. "Going to" could be any time in the future. We are all going to die. Not all of us are about to die.

Comment: "We are all going to die" means we all intend to die. Here, "going to" expresses our intention or determination. But not all of us are determined to die!

Comment: But I agree that "about to" implies immediacy. "The man is about to die" means the man is on the verge of death. "The man is going to die" means his death will happen in the future, usually quite soon.

Comment: I don't hear any connotation of "intention" or "determination" in "going to". It's simple futurity.

Comment: It's not my personal opinion. Collins dictionary says : "You say that you are going to do something to express your intention or determination to do it." https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-going-to

Comment: In that case, it's the "saying" that carries the intention/determination. The "going to" is simply the future. Consider: If he is trying to climb Mount Everest, and I say "He is going to succeed.", is that expressing intention or determination on anyone's part?

Comment: "We use be going to + Infinitive to talk about plans, ... emphasises the idea of intention, or a decision that has already been made : We're going to get a new car soon." [Michael Swan]

Comment: _I am going to_ can imply intention, but _You are going to enjoy that ice cream_ and _It is going to rain_ are just predictions of what will happen. See the first definition provided by Collins.

Comment: "Another use of the going to is to predict the future on the basis of present evidence : Look at the sky. It's going to rain". [Michael Swan] .On the basis of the present evidence of Corona virus pandemic situation only, you can now say : "We are all going to die".

Comment: We don't need coronavirus to predict that everybody is going to die (eventually) on the basis of current evidence.  But there are a range of uses of "going to" and they overlap with other future tenses. Often "I will" and "I'm going to" mean the same.

Comment: Who was it who is reported to have said on their death bed "I'm  going to,... or about to... die.... both are used."

Answer (score -1):

From this discussion, we can draw the following conclusion:

'About to" implies "IMMEDIACY". "The man is about to die" means "The man is on the verge of death : he will die immediately.

But "The man is going to die", here, means that there are certain present situation or evidence on the basis of which you can PREDICT that he will die quite soon .

Michael Swan says that "be going to + Infinitive" structure often emphasises the idea of intention. However, there is no connotation of intention in the sentence, "The man is going to die." In other words, "going to die" doesn't necessarily mean "intending to die".

And another interesting point is that both the sentences convey that he will die, but one (about to...) will occur sooner than the other (going to...).

Comment: Please don't answer your own questions! It's unlikely that anyone would interpret 'going to die' as 'intending to commit suicide'.

Comment: There's still no connotation of intention in "The man is going to die.:" None.

Comment: (1) The man is about to die --->> The man will die immediately.  (2) The man is going to die --->> It is predicted that the man will die soon.  Are these two explanations ok?